# How can we fix the "cannot resolve symbol" problem in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, constants

I'm making an android application for a RadioPad : barcode scanner working on Android and I have a problem in recieving the barcode information.

#### The problem is that Android Studio cannot resolve symbol "Constants".

The RadioPad I'm working on is Zebra MC3200 working on Android 4.1 and Upper.

I'm working on this library : barcode_scanner_library_v2.4.6.0

I tried to import ***android.provider.SyncStateContract.Constants*** but it made a problem with "BARCODE_RECEIVED" as shown below :

Link for full image :

A1 : https://i.stack.imgur.com/AkrVF.png   (Imports)

A2 : https://i.stack.imgur.com/6b9FQ.png    (Code)

And when I remove it :
No problem with "BARCODE_RECEIVED"

Link for full image

B1 : https://i.stack.imgur.com/g2HAn.png   (Imports)

B2 : https://i.stack.imgur.com/UXQUz.png    (Code)

Here there is a problem with "BARCODE_RECEIVED" : Cannot resolve symbol BARCODE_RECIEVED

```java
package com.example.zebrascanner;

import com.zebra.scannercontrol.*;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.provider.SyncStateContract.Constants;

private final Handler dataHandler = new Handler(){
        public void handleMessage (Message msg){
            switch (msg.what){
                case Constants.BARCODE_RECEIVED :
                    TextView textViewScanData =  findViewById(R.id.txt_result);
                    Barcode barcode = (Barcode) msg.obj;
                    textViewScanData.append(new String(barcode.getBarcodeData()));
            }
        }
    };
```

And here there is a problem with "Constants" : Cannot resolve symbol Constants :

```java
package com.example.zebrascanner;

import com.zebra.scannercontrol.*;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
//import android.provider.SyncStateContract.Constants;

private final Handler dataHandler = new Handler(){
        public void handleMessage (Message msg){
            switch (msg.what){
                case Constants.BARCODE_RECEIVED :
                    TextView textViewScanData =  findViewById(R.id.txt_result);
                    Barcode barcode = (Barcode) msg.obj;
                    textViewScanData.append(new String(barcode.getBarcodeData()));
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: Hello Haykel, welcome to SO! Can you post a link to the library you're using? It will help users further investigate if the problem is you doing something wrong, or the library being misused :)

Comment: Hi, yes for sure, here is a link for the Scanner SDK for Android where you will find the library : [link](https://www.zebra.com/us/en/support-downloads/software/developer-tools/scanner-sdk-for-android.html) @MartinMarconcini